# Radio button inside two foreach loops not getting checked

Tags: php, html, css

My code works like this. If a parent product has two variants, it creates two div (one hidden). When I click on radio button, it shows its relevant div & hides the other.

Now on page load, by default checked property doesn't work on any radio button.

Here is my code:

```
$pid=2;
foreach($query as $row){
  echo "<div class='$row['id']' <?php if($row['id']!=$pid){ ?>
        style='display:none;' <?php } ?>>";
  echo $row['name'];
  $variants=$db->query("SELECT * FROM products where pid=$pid");
    foreach($variants as $r){
       if($pid==$r['id']){ //I checked this, condition is fine
         echo "<input type='radio' checked>".$r['name'];
       }
       else{
         echo "<input type='radio'>".$r['name'];
       }
    }
}
```

Also when I click on other radio button, it shows its relevant div & hides the other but again no radio button is checked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try replacing "SELECT * FROM products where pid=$pid"; with "SELECT * FROM products where pid="$pid;

Comment: My all content is loading fine, no case of a typo in query string

Comment: Try with checked="checked"

Comment: are you sure it is going inside the `if` condition at all ?

Comment: You provide us with a non reproducable issue. Please provide a jsfiddle (with static HTML in stead of database connection) that shows the error. This could be browser and version related, cache, etc etc

Comment: Yes, tried echoing 'Hello' inside `if`, it displays it

Comment: @Masiorama That didn't help

Comment: Missing mandatory name in the input?

Comment: @mvbrakel well, as stated here (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)), all the radio input of the same group are supposed to have the same name attribute, not empty.

Comment: I'm trying to create jsFiddle for it, hope that can help

Comment: @mvbrakel Are you sure 100%? What if the missing name makes the browser unable to correctly check the right input? ... deleting your previous wrong comment/being sarcastic about my seggestion doesn't help the opener anyway, does it?

Comment: @Masiorama With your request, tried adding the same name attribute, that didn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: @ShanilSoni sorry pal, it was just a guess.

Comment: @mvbrakel we don't know which browser the OP is using.

Comment: @Masiorama exactly my point. This was my last comment to you. Please stay on the exact topic and make sure your findings are correct

Comment: @mvbrakel I was not able to crate a problem with static html in jsFiddle, can I explain it in a different way? I can attach screenshots

Comment: @ShanilSoni But you have a problem in your browser with displaying that specific code right? Please copy paste the source from that bit into a jsfiddle or in this question. So the actual rendered HTML by the browser

Comment: @mvbrakel Why would it be a bad thing to suggest things that MIGHT work in the **comments**?